# facebook GraphAPI post with Profile picture link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

using the Graph API I try to create a post - including a users picture.
In the documentation I found: - you can get the elements picture with
http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/picture - where XXXX is the id of the object (user).

And ...image src='http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/picture'... works fine.

My problem now - I try to create a post via ...me/feed passing this link as picture parameter.
When I do this - I get an error calling the graph API.
If I use a static link (to an existing image) posting works fine.

My goal is to use the users profile picture in the post.
Is this (passing a picture to "feed") only possible with static images?
Or is there a way to use the http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/picture link (and I make just a mistake somewhere else)?

Manfred

Comment: Followup - to avoid the problem I now retrieve the image url from the user data.
It' something like http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs623.ash1/27379_XXXXXXXXXX_3547_q.jpg - but using this link also fails. If I use http://iphone.pp-p.com/images/xxxx.jpg instead posting works.
The link to the profile picture - if pasted in a browser address line works.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine as what the GRAPH API does is it gives you a static URL to the profile image. So, what's the exact error you get ?

Answer (score 0):

the error message tells you the problem. you cannot use it because:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream: http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/215958041750734\/picture"}}
```

FBCDN means "FaceBook Content Delivery Network", so it wouldn't matter if you use the ID/picture URL or the end URL; they won't allow it by policy. Why the policy? No clue. And it's not likely they'll tell you, judging by their lack of response on their developer's discussion boards.